# Acessar Array dentro de Array

Tags: javascript

Boa noite, sou iniciante em JavaScript e estou estudando arrays. Me surgiu uma duvida, como faço para acessar um item que está na array dentro de outra array?

ex:`var numeros = [[01,02,03,04,05],[03,04,05]];`

E como eu faria um laço para verificar se os itens das duas arrays são iguais?

Desde já agradeço.

Answer (score 0):

Pensa que essa array exterior tem `A, B, C`. Para aceder a esses valores seria, respectivamente, `numeros[0]`, `numeros[1]`, `numeros[2]`. Continuando esse raciocínio, `numeros[0][0]` seria o `01` que está dentro da primeira "sub-"array; e `numeros[1][0]` seria o `03` na segunda "sub-"array.

Para saber se todos os items das sub-arrays são iguais podes fazer assim:

```js
const numeros = [
  ["01", "02", "03", "04", "05"],
  ["03", "04", "05"]
];

const iguais = (a, b, strict) => {

  return a.length === b.length && a.every((el, i) => b.includes(el) && !strict || el === b[i])
}

console.log(iguais([1, 2], [2, 1])); // true
console.log(iguais([1, 2], [2, 1], true)); // false
console.log(iguais([1, 2], [1, 2], true)); // true
console.log(iguais(numeros[0], numeros[1])); // false
```

Para saber se uma array inclui a outra podes fazer assim:

```js
const numeros = [
  ["01", "02", "03", "04", "05"],
  ["03", "04", "05"]
];

const includes = (a, b) => {
  return a.every(el => b.includes(el));
}

console.log(includes(numeros[0], numeros[1])); // false
console.log(includes(numeros[1], numeros[0])); // true
```